# Move around the buttons for this jquery lightbox

Tags: jquery, lightbox

http://leandrovieira.com/projects/jquery/lightbox/

Ok this is quite advanced I assume. I have this lightbox, although if you look at the demo you will see that the 'prev' and 'next' button appear towards the top left and right respectively and only when you hover.

I'd rather them appear next to the close button at the bottom so they remain constant and are visible always.

Anyone know what code changes I need to make to have this in place. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Been playing around with the code for the past hour and have no idea what I'm doing and nothing has worked so far.

Answer (score 0):

Change the CSS jquery.lightbox-0.5.css

```
#lightbox-nav {
position: absolute;
top: 0;  /* THIS SETTING SETS THE TOP POSITION */
left: 0;
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
z-index: 10;
 }
```

and

```
 #lightbox-nav-btnPrev { 
left: 0; /* THIS SETTING SETS THE LEFT POSITION FOR PREV */
float: left;
 }
#lightbox-nav-btnNext { 
right: 0; /* THIS SETTING SETS THE RIGHT POSITION FOR NEXT */
float: right;
 }
```

to suit your needs...

Comment: I've tried that but didn't work. It delves more deeper into to the actual js files :(